# Editing ArrayLists in Android ListView

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I have an ArrayAdapter that's using an ArrayList to display data in a ListView.

During the course of the activity, I sometimes need to edit the ArrayList by adding and deleting items.

Is there a difference if I call the add/delete functions on the actual ArrayAdapter vs. the underlying ArrayList? Which is better to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the adapter methods. This will automatically notify your adapter (and thus the bound list) that your data has changed.

Comment: Oh. So it's the same as editing the backing arraylist, and then calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`?

Comment: By examining the source (http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.6_r2/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#ArrayAdapter.add%28java.lang.Object%29) you can see that for the most part, yes this is true.

Comment: So does it matter that if I'm adding lots of items, it's essentially calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` each time. Is it better to add to underlying arraylist, and only call `notifyDataSetChanged()` once?

Comment: That's certainly something to consider. I was initially just going for the simple straightforward answer, but if you're adding a lot of items, from a performance perspective it may make sense to add them to the `ArrayList` and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` yourself, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Some times it is necessary (or at least more convenient) to modify the ArrayList (e.g., is a field of some other class, or it is being modified by other thread that does not know about the adapter).

In those cases, you will need to call [adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29)